# ¿Why this returns 0?

Tags: mysql, sql

Thats return me 0. Why? i need som like this 1/8 + 1/7 + 1/6....1/m
Srry for my code, im learning sql.

```sql
delimiter //

drop function if exists divide;

create function divide(m int) returns decimal(30,3) deterministic
begin
    declare m int;
    declare n decimal(30,3) default 0;
    declare x decimal(30,3) default 0;
    
    while m>=1 do
        set n=n+x;
        select 1/m into x;
        set m=m-1;
    end while;
    
    return n;
end;//

delimiter ;

select divide(8);
```

Comment: [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388759/11683)

Comment: Hint: you have two `m int`s..

Comment: 1/m is integer division and returns 0, i suppose

Comment: `1/m` is likely to give 0 for m with a magnitude greater than 2. Perhaps you meant `1.0/m`.

Comment: Ok, its solved, thx all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all, the solution was that i declared two times m.